# How can I open the html file on safari extension

Tags: html, safari-extension

I'm creating a safari extension.

I know how to open the URL.

like this

```
var newWin = safari.application.openBrowserWindow();

newWin.activeTab.url = "www://someSite.co.jp";
```

But, how can I open the file made by myself in the way like the mentioned example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`someTab.url = safari.extension.baseURI + myFilePath`

[AccessingResourcesWithinYourExtensionFolder](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AccessingResourcesWithinYourExtensionFolder/AccessingResourcesWithinYourExtensionFolder.html)